# Encoding a string as per RFC 1738 in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, twitter

I want to encode a string as per RFC 1738 in NodeJs app. This is required in Twitter API [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only).
I found no package to achieve this. Has someone done this already? I wanted too register my webhook url to twitter app.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the native javascript method [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

To be compliant with the RFC you would need to handle these additional characters:

```
function rawurlencode (str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str)
    .replace(/!/g, '%21')
    .replace(/'/g, '%27')
    .replace(/\(/g, '%28')
    .replace(/\)/g, '%29')
    .replace(/\*/g, '%2A')
}
```

[Reference](http://locutus.io/php/url/rawurlencode/)

Comment: I googled around in relation to your comment. I came accross rawurlencode which uses RFC 1738. I am following below link to encode to RFC 1738 now.
http://locutus.io/php/url/rawurlencode/

Comment: ok, it seems like you need to handle additional characters in addition to what encodeURIComponent provides. I'll update my answer.